# Request.Url.AbsoluteUri displaying wrong url

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

```
  var img = new Image();
  img.ImageUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "~/_layouts/images/Cv.Knowit/pie-1-4.png";
```

I am getting to this site

> wingtipserver/SitePages/
>       Generated%20Cv.aspx?WikiPageMode=Edit&InitialTabId=Ribbon.EditingTools.
>   CPEditTab&VisibilityContext=WSSWikiPage

So the image will not display. What could be the problem? I am getting an incorrect image url.

How do I get the correct image url?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Request.Url.AbsoluteUri - that is the Uri of the page you're on, including the query string, presumably what you spit out there (the rest is probably being cut off because it's invalid).

~ is a special character in Asp.Net server controls which will get you the root of your application, which may be what you want, or perhaps you want ~site or ~sitecollection which SharePoint will treat specially. [(Read more here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337781/creating-custom-url-tokens-in-asp-net-a-la-moss)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SPContext.Current.Web.Url to get absolute url of current web.

Comment: i want the image to get from the root of my application,

Comment: i only get this url http://wingtipserver~/_layouts/images/Cv.Knowit/pie-1-4.png

Comment: if i only use @"~/_layouts/images/Cv.Knowit/pie-2-4.png"; i will get cannot find the url , that because i am trying to do Request.Url.AbsoluteUri  my friend did exacly the same on his server its working but not on mine..